# Accessibility and Autoscroll

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I have a scrollable list of items, with a possibility to add a new item to the list. The new item always appears on the top of the list. Also in order to inform the user that an item has been successfully created, we use auto-scroll to the top of the list (if it's scrolled).

I also have another case of auto-scroll in the same UI, when the user types some invalid data in the field and press the submit button. Right now, in such a case we put focus on the first invalid field and do smooth auto-scroll to it.

Also, I have a requirement to implement the accessibility WCAG 2.1 AA standard.
However, if I understand correctly, the described above behaviors break 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide WCAG point, unless we provide a pause button, but as it's very quick autoscrolling, less than 1 second, the pause button doesn't make any sense.

As an alternative, we thought to implement something like accessibility mode, which would disable any autoscrolling.

So, my question is, does it the best approach for such a problem? Do my cases really break 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide criteria, or I misunderstand it?

Thank you for any help on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that this kind of auto-scroll not breaking 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide criteria, as in order to be the case for this criteria scrolling should:

1. Starts automatically - yes
2. Lasts more than five seconds - no, it's less than 1 second
3. Presented in parallel with other content - yes

So, looks like it's not a problem at all!